# Integration over multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Consider $B=H+M$ and the variables $H$ and $M$ which make up the following integral:
\begin{align}
\int_{B_1}^{B_2} HdB&=\int_{H_1+M_1}^{H_2+M_2} Hd(H +M) \\&=\int_{H_1}^{H_2}HdH+\int_{M_1}^{M_2} HdM \\
&= \frac{H^2}{2}\Big|_{H_1}^{H_2}+HM\Big|_{M_1}^{M_2}\\
&=\frac{H_2^2}{2}-\frac{H_1^2}{2}+HM_2-HM_1
\end{align}
However, I am not sure about the solution as I do not know what to insert for $H$?

Comment: There's no answer to that because your first integral is not well defined. Suppose in the first case you integrate over a path $(H(t),M(t))=(0,(1-t)(H_1+M_1)+t(H_2+M_2))$ with $t$ from $0$ to $1$, then the outcome would be $0$. On the other hand, if you integrate over $(H(t),M(t))=(1-t)(H_1,M_1)+t(H_2,M_2)$, you'll generically get an answer different from $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It is the second case, how do I have to define the first integral properly then?

Comment: Precisely define the path over which you integrate, then the integral becomes $\int_P HdB=\int_{t=0}^{t=1}((1-t)H_1+tH_2)(H_2+M_2 - H_1-M_1)dt$. If the path $P$ is the one I defined in my second example.

Comment: Now you are integrating over $t$, then you need to know how the functions H(t) and M(t) vary over t. However, this I do not know... I want to integrate over $B$, $H$ or $M$. Is there a way to rewrite the integral to make it integratable over these variables?